Is it possible to auto Disable an azure self hosted agent if it fails a job?
Is it possible to auto Disable an azure self hosted agent if it fails a job?
I am doing appium based android UI testing through azure self hosted agents. Occasionally one of the PCs will lose UsB debugging authorization to the android device. When this happens the agent will return Failed quite quickly and continue to grab test after test returning Failed jobs.
Is there a way to set a condition where if an agent returns a Failed job that we can disable the agent to prevent it from picking up any future jobs until I am able to manually address the issue?

Add a step to the corresponding job with condition failed() that disables the agent that is currently running that job.

Hi @KyleLeighton, Good day to you. Have you got a chance to check the workaround below to disable the current build agent via API? Hope it may help resolve your query in this post. Thx for the time and sharing.

No, not really, but you could add a conditional step or job and use the API to disable the runner using the PATCH method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1
You may need to grant the Azure Pipelines user additional permissions to manage the Agent Pool.

There is no functionality out-of-the-box to disable a self-hosted if the agent job running on it is failed. You may consider the workaround to add a script to call this API to disable the current agent, on the condition that any of the previous steps within the same agent job is failed. We can collect the pool id from the URL like that in the screenshot below and retrieve the agentId with the predefined agent variable $(Agent.Id), which will always point to the agent that current job is running on.
Here is a sample YAML pipeline for your reference.
jobs:
- job: FailedAgentJob
  pool: Default # Whose pool id is 1
  variables:
    poolId: 1
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error;]'Represent some failed tests on the current self-hosted agent'"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]"
    displayName: Some UI tests
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Agent.Id - $(Agent.Id)"
      Write-Host "Agent.Name - $(Agent.Name)"
      Write-Host "Agent.MachineName - $(Agent.MachineName)"
      
      $URL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$(poolId)/agents/$(Agent.Id)?api-version=7.2-preview.1"
      $headers = @{
        'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + "$(System.AccessToken)"
        'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
      }
      $body = @{
        id = $(Agent.Id)
        enabled = $false
      } | ConvertTo-Json
      
      Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method Patch -Headers $headers -Body $body
    condition: failed()



Since the sample request authenticates against the $(System.AccessToken) of the pipeline service accounts to disable the current self-hosted agent, make sure to grant Administrator role for either (or both) of the pipeline service accounts corresponding to the job authorization scope in your organization & project settings.


There are security implications to making the Build account  pool administrator. You'll need to check whether you can lie with those permissions. This way a rogue build script can register a new agent and a few other things.

Thanks for the insights. Perhaps we may consider using a PAT instead for authentication. I agree that the pool administrators should indeed evaluate the security risks.
